# Which game is shown in this image from apple website?

Tags: game-identification

Found this image over on Apple's website. Can I know what game it is?

[image: Image from Website]

It is the iPad in the center of the image from the [Apple iPad mini 4 site](https://www.apple.com/ipad-mini-4/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The game is called X-Runner.

Sources:

- [iTunes](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/x-runner/id569768801?mt=8)
- [Google Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.droidhen.game.xrunner&hl=en)
- [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=621q0zHmzEc)

Comment: ...given that the image was from an Apple website, wouldn't the iTunes app store link be more useful?

Comment: @Powerlord added more sources.